# Form data with helper class in Laravel

Tags: laravel

To prevent the duplications of the codes, I used the Laravel composer service to develop some common data fields such as dropdown & list items. When I tried to edit some data I want to display data from the DB inside the select option and auto-select the data from the DB. composer service I mean I am populating dropdown list as class as in below.

> GradesComposer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\View\Composers;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Grade;

class GradesComposer{
    public function compose(View $view){
        $view->with('grades_datas', Grade::select('grades.id','grades.grade')->orderBy('grade')->get());
    }
}
```

> GnamesComposer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\View\Composers;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Gname;

class GnamesComposer{
    public function compose(View $view){
        $view->with('gnames_datas', Gname::select('gnames.id','gnames.gname')->orderBy('gname')->get());
    }
}
```

> GsizesComposer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\View\Composers;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Gsize;

class GsizesComposer{
    public function compose(View $view){
        $view->with('gsizes_datas', Gsize::select('gsizes.id','gsizes.gsize')->orderBy('gsize')->get());
        // dd($view);
    }
}
```

My app service provider class is like below.

> AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Http\View\Composers\GradesComposer;
use App\Http\View\Composers\GnamesComposer;
use App\Http\View\Composers\GsizesComposer;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    public function boot(){
        View::composer('partials.grade.*', GradesComposer::class);
        View::composer('partials.grade.*', GnamesComposer::class);
        View::composer('partials.grade.*', GsizesComposer::class);
    }
}
```

> gradeDropDown.blade.php

```
 <select name="" id="">
    @foreach ($grades_datas as $grade_data)
        @foreach ($specification->grades as $grade)
            <option value="{{ $grade_data->id }}"
                {{ old('grade', $grade->id) == $grade_data->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $grade_data->grade }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

> gnameDropDown.blade.php

```
<select name="{{ $field ?? 'gname' }}" id="gname" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
    <option disabled selected>Select Grade Name</option>
    @foreach ($gnames_datas as $gname_data)
        @foreach ($specification->gnames as $gname)
            <option value="{{ $gname->id }}" {{ old('gname', $gname->id) == $gname_data->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $gname_data->gname }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

> gsizeDropDown.blade.php

```
<select name="{{ $field ?? 'gsize' }}" id="gsize" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
    <option disabled selected>Select Grade Name</option>
    @foreach ($gsizes_datas as $gsize_data)
        @foreach ($specification->gsizes as $gsize)
            <option value="{{ $gsize->id }}" {{ old('gsize', $gsize->id) == $gsize_data->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{ $gsize_data->gsize }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

According to the above codes when I try to edit I can display all data within related elements which are going to edit. **But the problem is occurring when I try to insert new data. Dropdown list data which I am grabbing with from the classes( grades, gnames & gsizes) not list down within the select options**. gnames, grades & gsizes sepereate database tables and each have many to many relationships with specifications table which is common. when I am creating specifications grades, gnames & gsizes will grab from the db into select option element.
Can anyone help me to identify & solve my expectation.

My create & edit methods in controller like in below.

> SpecificationController.php

```
public function create(){
  $specification = new Specification();
  return view('home.specification.create', compact('specification'));
} 

public function edit(Specification $specification){
  $specification = Specification::find($specification->id);
  return view('home.specification.edit', compact('specification'));
}
```

Also my view is like below.

```
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-header">Grades</div>
        <div class="form-row form-control-sm">
            <div class="form-group col">
                
                @include('partials.grade.gradeDropDown')

                @error('grade')
                    <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">

                @include('partials.grade.gnameDropDown')
                @error('gname')
                    <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">

                @include('partials.grade.gsizeDropDown')
                @error('gsize')
                    <p style="color: red">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by composer function ?

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: Could you please most the code talked about so people can have a look? We can't just tell you what is wrong out of thin air.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and I've edited my question.